# Use define constant in another file

Tags: php, constants

I have a small piece of code that was written in previous version of PHP (not 5.3) and I find it odd for the interpreter to catch a cross use of a constant as a notice message then finally cough up a fatal error when the constant is defined in a file that is different from the one the notice is being reported.
That is, for example, I define my constant in file A which is initialized when the program starts

```
define('SOME_CONSTANT','something');
```

and in file B.php

```
require_once('A.php');
Call-function-that-uses-fileA's-SOME_CONSTANT
```

File B is reported with notice message and a fatal error.

The fatal error can be roughly described as

> require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required ....

in which "...." stands for a long line of included paths that may or maynot be related to the current file B at all. I am grateful for any help or advice you offer.

Is this caused by my use of new PHP version while my code was written in old one ? How can I fix these messages without reinstalling the PHP ?

**Edit**:

The only reason I would not want to reinstalling the PHP is that because I don't want to always change the PHP whenever I have to work with a new project. Now it may be old, what if later I need to use the latest version, re-downloading the new one and deleting the old one psss?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your constant, check `file_exists('A.php')` in B.php

Comment: Given error definitely signals that file A.php could not be found by the interpreter. You have to check if A.php is a correct path for inclusion.

Comment: @Darcy: Please review this question. If you were able to solve your problem please add your solution as an answer below and / or accept one of the answers to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 4):

> *I know this was and old question but in case anyone is stumbling onto it...*

Unfortunately the `require_once('A.php');` call is searching for the `a.php` file in the same directory as file `B.php`. If you wish to include the `A.php` file you need to give it the full directory path to the file OR modify the `php.ini` file's `include_path` string to include the parent directory housing `A.php`.

If you don't want to go modifying the `php.ini` file then simply giving it the full path to the file will do it.

*@Binaek:* The `__DIR__` magic variable would simply return the full path that `B.php` is in which would not work because the a.php file does not appear to be in that directory otherwise the `require_once` would work as is.

Answer (score 2):

you should define a constant on your desired file like:

```
define("APPLICATION_NAME","my app");
```

then use in another files like this:

```
include_once 'yourfile_with_constant_value';
$value = APPLICATION_NAME;
```

please be care full to define constant with uppercase word.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once(__DIR___.'/A.php');
```

`__DIR__` gives the current directory of the executing file.